# Checking only one radio button after retrieving data from a database

Tags: php, mysql

How do I output a radio button with each data in a column from my database and make sure they can only be one data selected.  I tried using this code but you could select multiple category at the same time

```
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){?>
  <form action="post" method="product_category.php">
    <input type = "radio" name="interest" value="<?php echo $row['product_category'];?>" checked="checked">
    <?php echo $row['product_category'] ;
      echo $row['category_description'] ;
      ?>
  </form>
```

[image]

Comment: Code has lot of errors. Can you show example data what you are getting from database?

Comment: What is the condition for check radio button ? as per your code there is no condition for check radio button

Comment: OK, @elby only one radio button as to be checked

Comment: We need some condition for check that radio button, that means if($cat==='product') then check like that

Comment: where's this code you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U have to loop inside the form. Since you were looping the complete form, the radio buttons were not behaving as a group of radio buttons as they were in different container forms.

```
    <form>
<?php
    While ($row = mysqli_fetch_data($result) {?>
    <Input type =radio name="interest" value=<?php echo $row['category']? > <?php echo $row['category']. "". $row['description'] ;?>
    <?php } ?> 
    </form>
```

Comment: remove the space in all the `<? php`. OP or others might think it's valid syntax which it isn't.

Comment: actually i have copy pasted his code only and have made the changes in that. Anyway thanx for correcting me

Answer (score 0):

You can select only 1 button like this.

```
<input type="radio" name="locked" value="yes" 
<?php 
     if($row['locked']=='yes'){?> 
         checked="checked" 
<?php }?> />yes
<input type="radio" name="locked" value="no" 
<?php 
     if($row['locked']=='no'){?> 
       checked="checked" 
<?php }?>/>No
```